# Grouping Date by month in MVC Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

i would like to count the number of new users in one month. However this is the output i am receiving. How do i go about grouping the repeated months into just "Jan", "Nov". Thank you so much for your help.

[Image of output](http://s1174.photobucket.com/user/jmetjm/media/users_perMonth_zpspsbrwiy6.png.html)

```html
public ActionResult UserPerMonth()
{

    var _con = new DBEntities();
    ArrayList xValue = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList yValue = new ArrayList();
    var results = (from c in _con.Users select c);
    results.ToList().ForEach(rs => yValue.Add(rs.id.ToString().Count()));
    results.ToList().ForEach(rs => xValue.Add(rs.date.Value.ToString("MMM-yyyy")));

    var chart = new Chart(width: 300, height: 200)
                .AddTitle("Users per month")
                .AddLegend()
                .AddSeries(
                chartType: "Column",
                xValue: xValue,
                yValues: yValue)
                .GetBytes("png");
     return File(chart, "image/png");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more concise way of doing it but this is working for me. Add a class for your Chart Data e.g.

```
public class ChartData
{
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use a linq query with groupby and count to get the data and put it in to the ChartData type, then move these values to the relevant axis:

```
public ActionResult UserPerMonth()
{

    var _con = new DBEntities();
    ArrayList xValue = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList yValue = new ArrayList();

    var results = (from c in _con.Users select c);

    var axis = results.GroupBy(r => r.date.Value.ToString("MMM-yyyy"))
            .Select(r => new ChartData
            {
                Month = r.Key,
                Count = r.Count()
            }).ToList();

    foreach (var item in axis)
    {
        xValue.Add(item.Month);
        yValue.Add(item.Count);
    }


    var chart = new Chart(width: 300, height: 200)
        .AddTitle("Users per month")
        .AddLegend()
        .AddSeries(
            chartType: "Column",
            xValue: xValue,
            yValues: yValue)
        .GetBytes("png");
    return File(chart, "image/png");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i think there is a typo for this part Month = n.Key,
Count = n.Count(), however the code does not display the chart @James

Comment: Apologies, yes have fixed the typo - can you try that. If not please set break point and see what is value of `axis`?